# footer hides when moves on next page

Tags: javascript, ipad, jquery-mobile

I have html structure like this

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <a href="#p2" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="b" data-iconpos="right">next pagey</a>  
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

<div id="p2" data-role="page" data-theme="b">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Content</h1> 
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Content</h1>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

But when i click on next page and next page comes in with auto-added back btn in header, when I click on back button previous page appears but footer dissappears..

in FF working ok, but not in ipad simulator

Comment: on your first page try adding a id as well: <div id="p1" data-role="page" data-theme="b">

Answer (score 1):

Getting fixed footers to work is a pain for the JQM team. I think it's just another little bug that is caused by unforseen circumstances. Well, nevermind...

A bit of insight:
Those *darn* mobile browsers have no support of fixed CSS positioning, so this is done with javascript and absolute position (and a ton of hacks - I bet)

This should already give you a clue...

**If the behaviour isn't specific just to the emulator (quite possible!)** and the problem remains after you fill the page with contents (I mean - finish writing the application) then all you need to do is to kickstart the code that repositions the footer. I'd do it like that:

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(){ $(window).trigger('orientationchange') });
```

The orientationchange event should work. You can also try `resize` if orientationchange causes any new problems.

Comment: try triggering on `body` instead of `window` and see if it helps. And make sure the code is actually fired. Add a `console.log` inside the function and see if it comes up.